# Show one default option in Autocomplete Search

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a Jquery autocomplete -

```
<input type="text" id="contactName" class="form-control input-lg formData textVal" placeholder="Contact Name&#42;"/>
```

With JQuery code as follows -

```
$('#contactName').autocomplete({
        source: contacts,
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        open: function(event) {},
        close: function() {},
        focus: function(event,ui) {

        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.item.id == 'create-new-contact'){
                //do something to create a new contact
            }else{
                $('#contactIDVal').val(ui.item.id);
            }
        }
    }).on('focus', function(){$(this).autocomplete("search");});
    $("#contactName").autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        ul.prepend('<li value="create-new-contact">Create New Contact</li>');
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            self._renderItemData( ul, item );
        });
    };
```

What I want is to show 'Create New Contact' option always. Even if the typed text matches with elements in my array **or NOT**. I am able to achieve the first part, but when the typed text **do not match** with any items in the array, _renderMenu is not even called. How do I show one default option always whether or not the typed text matches anything in the source array.

In addition to that, The default item that I creating here -

```
ul.prepend('<li value="create-new-contact">Create New Contact</li>');
```

is giving me following error when I am taking my mouse over this item -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).menufocus (http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js:3012:49)
    at HTMLUListElement.handlerProxy (http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js:726:7)
    at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:8549)
    at HTMLUListElement.r.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:5252)
    at Object.trigger (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:7650)
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:15517)
    at Function.each (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:2:2975)
    at m.fn.init.each (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:2:835)
    at m.fn.init.trigger (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:15493)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._trigger (http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js:813:16)
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this without all this garbage?
Thanks

EDIT -
I solved it with the help of @ADyson

```
$('#contactName').autocomplete({
        source: contacts,
        response: function(event, ui){
            ui.content.push({id:'create-new-contact', label:'Create New Contact', value:'Create New Contact'});
        },
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        open: function(event) {},
        close: function() {},
        focus: function(event,ui) {

        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.item.id == 'create-new-contact'){
                //do some stuff here
            }else{
                $('#contactIDVal').val(ui.item.id);
            }
        }
    }).on('focus', function(){$(this).autocomplete("search");});
```

Comment: the "source" option can be a function. So you could use that to define a function which searches your database/array, but also inserts an extra item into the returned data with your default option. That's the cleanest option IMO. See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source for details on how to implement

Comment: I can do it that way, but the thing is, I have another autocomplete before this one, which makes a hit to DB and fetches everything for itself, plus everything for this particular autocomplete. I do not want to hit the DB again just for this one. I already have the data in the 'contacts' array once this autocomplete is created. Any other workaround to save DB hits and achieving what I want? I am open to ideas...

Comment: the function you give to "source" can still read from your contacts array, there's no requirement for a DB call. (After all, it's a function, you can make it do whatever you like!). It just means you can modify the contents of that before you display the suggestions to the user.

Comment: Another option which might actually be simpler and achieve the same effect is to handle the "response" event - you can manipulate the results there as well: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Comment: Oh okay, makes sense. Let me try that then.

Comment: Okay, in the approaches that you have suggested, what will happen if I type something which is not there in the source array? I still want a default option to be displayed in the auto-complete drop down.

Comment: if you inject the default value into the returned list of suggestions then it will always be displayed, no matter what the user types. A response is always returned to the user, even if it turns out to be empty. So using those methods you can intercept it and change it to include you default value. If you look at the docs for the "response" event that I gave you the link for, it says "This event is always triggered when a search completes, even if the menu will not be shown because there are no results" Therefore, if you then add a result, it will cause the menu to be shown.

Comment: Perfect! If you can post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution here is to inject the default value into the returned list of suggestions, then it can always be displayed no matter what the user types. This is much easier than trying to manipulate the generated HTML markup, which you were attempting.

There are two ways of doing this using the autocomplete's API:

1) Creating a custom data source. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source - The "source" option can be a function, in which you can do whatever you like, as long as you provide a list of responses back in a callback.

2) Handling the "repsonse" event. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response - This gives you access to the list of returned responses just before they are displayed to the user (even if there are no matching responses found, this event will still fire). At this point you can easily add your default item to the array of responses.

Personally of those, for what you want to do I think option 2 is the simplest.